# Unable to open a qlikview project

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

So I want to open a project already developed on another computer with Qlikview, but i can't do it, and i got this message:

> "**Your installation of Qlikview has exceeded the maximum number of document recoveries allowed for a Personal Edition license.**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the QV personal edition states QlikView Personal Edition works with local files only; you cannot share your QlikView file with another unregistered user, or load a QlikView file from another user.

Your options are either Buy licences or open it on the machine it was created on

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so there isn't a solution to this problem?

Comment: @ANAS89 If Matt's answer solved your problem, please take a few moments to accept his answer so that other users can benefit.